# Как объединить 2 таблицы на основе регулярных выражений?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, postgresql, join

Имеется 2 таблицы со следующими столбцами.

table1:

```
ABCD1 Protein Expression measurement | Measurement | Variant
AKT1 Gene Mutation measurement | Measurement | Variant
ASXL3 Protein Expression measurement | Measurement | Variant
COL4A3 Protein Expression measurement | Measurement | Variant
```

table2:

```
ABCD1 (ATP binding cassette subfamily D member 1) gene variant measurement | Gene
AKT1 (AKT serine/threonine kinase 1) gene variant measurement | Gene
ASXL3 (ASXL transcriptional regulator 3) gene variant measurement | Gene
COL4A3 (collagen type IV alpha 3 chain) gene variant measurement | Gene
```

Можно ли как-то, используя регулярные выражения, их объединить?

Пробовала через regexp_matches, like, но не очень понимаю синтаксис джойна с регулярками.

В итоге хотелось бы получить

```
 ABCD1 Protein Expression measurement | ABCD1 (ATP binding cassette subfamily D member 1) gene variant measurement | Gene
AKT1 Gene Mutation measurement | AKT1 (AKT serine/threonine kinase 1) gene variant measurement | Gene
ASXL3 Protein Expression measurement | ASXL3 (ASXL transcriptional regulator 3) gene variant measurement | Gene
COL4A3 Protein Expression measurement |COL4A3 (collagen type IV alpha 3 chain) gene variant measurement | Gene
```

Comment: Имеется в виду объединение по префиксу первых полей? да не проблема... да и регулярка тут не нужна. split_part() вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1.column1 column1_1,
       t2.column1 column1_2,
       t2.column2 column2_2
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON split_part(t1.column1, ' ', 1)=split_part(t2.column1, ' ', 1)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d38c8f0918f8146635b80fd66f4c61c3